# DropDown.Change will not fire if the user chnage the dropdown values using the keyboard (up & down ) arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following script insde my asp.net mvc razor view:-

```
$("#Server_RackID").change(function () {
            var idDC = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Server/LoadDataCenterByRackID")", { rackid: idDC },
            function (DCData) {
                var select = $("#Server_TMSRack_DataCenterID");

                $("#Server_TMSRack_DataCenterID").val(DCData.Value);

            });
        });
```

The script will fire when the Server_RackID  drop down is changed , but this chnage should be when the user select a new drop down values using the mouse. while if the user using the (up & down) arrows scroll over the drop down items,  then the script will not fire ? so can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks

Comment: It is `change` not `chnage` as you wrote it in all occurences in your question, please!

Comment: you can change the value of select box using keyup event. Then the change event will trigger.

Comment: Jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/rkumar670/3SNgu/ working when changing the values from keyboard

Comment: @RahulKumar r u sure it work with keyboard,, did u try it ...!!

Comment: Yes i create it and try it is working fine

Comment: no it will not work ..

Comment: my old code will work on IE , but not on firefox ... and yours is the same

Answer (score -1):

You need to bind the event to both `change` and `keyup`, like this:

```
$("#Server_RackID").on('change keyup', function (event) { 
    //Do something
});
```

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNn4K/)

Comment: @FurquanKhan - I don't understand what you mean. This does work and I've provided a fiddle.

Comment: It does not work as supposed. While all the dropdown options are visible, does your code work that way.

Comment: the problem with your code is that the script will fire even if the user do not chnage the drop down value. i mean if i just chnage the focus using "tab" without changing the dro down value , then the script will fire .... i think this problem with .change is related to firefox only, while on IE and chrome the .change is working well..